# how to convert the below MongoDB query to c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

how to convert the below `MongoDB` command in c#?

```
db.Report.find({DateAndTime:{$gt: ISODate("2014-11-13T18:43:33.868Z"),$lt:ISODate("2014-11-14T23:43:33.868Z")}})
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public List<Report> FindRports()
{
    var reportContext = new ReportContext();
    var builder = Builders<Reprot>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Gt(x => x.GeneratedAtUtc, new DateTime(2014, 11, 13, 18, 43 ,33 ,868)) 
               & builder.Lt(x => x.GeneratedAtUtc, new DateTime(2014, 11, 14, 18, 43, 33, 868));
    var result = reportContext.ReportCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: yeah i have tried the above query but in that case it neglects the border cases.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something?

```
var greaterThen = new DateTime(2014,11,13) //or as you want
var smallerThen = new DateTime(2014,11,13) //or as you want
var report = db.Report.Where(r => r.Created > greaterThen && r.Created < smallerThen).ToList();
```

Use propername though :)

Comment: yeah i have tried the above query but in that case it neglects the border cases.

Comment: Your mongoDB query would that do too right? Because you are using GT, or is that greaterAndEquals? if so, you can use ar report = db.Report.Where(r => r.Created >= greaterThen && r.Created <= smallerThen)